# Old animated Disney movie that explained math problems

Tags: story-identification, disney, animation

I remember watching an old Disney animated movie, that primarily was about math, which I think my dad made me watch to gain interest. Anyway, I'm fairly certain it featured at least Mickey and Donald, and I remember that a few scenes talked about how you could draw a star within another star if you drew it like a pentagram, and they explained the golden ratio where they used a shell to demonstrate the phenomenon. It was also animated in their classic Disney style back in the 60's and 50's. There's not much else that I can remember about it.

Comment: ...and my 5cents IMHO, these question was marked as "out of topic" but Donal Duck is a cartoon character https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck , so I think this shouldn't be marked as out of topic.a

Comment: @riccs_0x The presence of cartoon characters, including talking animals, does not in and of itself make a work on-topic.

Comment: @Politank-Z, and why not? If there is a question on meta or here please post it thanks

Comment: @riccs_0x Here is a meta conversation on it.  [https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy)

Comment: @Forral Thanks !!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this might be what you remember:

[Donald in Mathmagic Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_in_Mathmagic_Land)

[image]

Specifically, it goes into things like the Golden Ratio and pentagrams. In fact, From the description in the wiki, it seems like the pentagram was a running theme.

Comment: Yup, definitely it.

Comment: It also had the rather interesting discussion of angles by virtue of showing how you could use the diamonds on the table to determine the exact angle to hit all three bumpers and then sink the ball you planned to hit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdVRvYnqj6w

Comment: I remember the diamonds thing its interesting